# Does synchronized work on referenced/pointer variables?

Tags: java, android

So I know how synchronize keyword works in general but would the below work as I think it would work (ie two threads will not step on eachother's toes while adding or removing)

```
public MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
public MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2();

public class MyClass {
     private ArrayList<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();

     public ArrayList<String> GetArrayList() {
         return myString;
     }
     public MyClass() {
          new Thread(new Runnable {
               public void run() {
                   synchronized(myString) {
                       /* add or remove myString elements */
                   }
               }
          }).start();
     }

}


public class MyClass2 {
     // Pointer to myString
     ArrayList<String> refString;
     public MyClass2() {
          refString = myClass.GetArrayList();
          new Thread(new Runnable {
               public void run() {
                   synchronized(refString) {
                       /* add or remove refString elements */
                   }
               }
          }).start();
     }
     }
}
```

EDIT: next time i'll type this out in eclipse and copy&paste :)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to synchronize.

Comment: I was trying to synchronize myString, since both threads would add/remove elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work, but why not just use Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList)?

If all you are doing is ADD or REMOVE, and not check-then-act (eg. If !myList.contains { myList.add}) that's all you need, and you avoid making your code ugly with synchronized blocks

Comment: Thank you sir! NewKnowledge++

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would work. You're dealing with references to the same object so the same object will be locked and tested with the `synchronized` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First,Synchronized blocks work on Objects so if you are using an object for synchronizing your critical section,it would work. But what have you done inside your myClass2 constuctor.You are defining myClass constructor inside myClass2 constructor which is not a valid code.

Comment: Yeah, typed it out directly in browser so syntax might be off, but myClass is defined at the very top.